# Como mudar o tema de um blog wordpress já pronto

Tags: wordpress

Gostaria de saber se é possível alterar o layout de um blog de [video](http://video-news.tv) Wordpress e usando um tema já pronto semelhante [ao deste blog](http://blog2.com.br) ?

Comment: Sim. O código fonte de todos os temas ficam no diretório `wp-content/themes`. Basta acessar o tema desejado e alterá-lo conforme a necessidade, desde que em conforme com a licença do tema em questão.

Comment: Entendi. Isso pode ser feito pelo painel admin Wordpress mesmo ou pelo painel Cpanel da hospedagem no gerenciador de arquivos ? Eu procurei vídeos que mostrasse fazendo essa ação, mas não encontrei exceto, de como criar um tema do início. No meu caso eu gostaria de adicionar algumas funções a mais no tema e, fazer isso utilizando um tema já pronto, se caso souber de algum vídeo, explique melhor, ficarei grato pela ajuda. Eu já entendo um pouco de html mais nunca fiz muitas alterações exceto, mudar nomes do inglês para português.